# How to make a <div> expand to fill space, without stretching parent if there is no space to fill?

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table

In a page I am working on, I have a table inside of another table. The inner table may get quite large, so I want it to have `overflow-y: scroll` so it doesn't make the outer table unnecessarily large. I understand that to make this work, I need to put the inner table inside a div.

This works well enough: I can set the `height` of the `div` that is inside a `td`, and that div will scroll so the table contained inside it doesn't make the outer table huge.

But my scenario is a little bit more complex than this. The `td` that the `div` is in spans multiple rows. In the case that the total height of the rows it spans is greater than the height I've set for the div, I'd like the div to expand to take up the empty space.

Here is a jsFiddle which demonstrates the functionality I'm looking for: 
http://jsfiddle.net/g0h5bu75/
The `div` in the Nop `td` scrolls so it doesn't stretch that cell. If you add some content to the Bar/Baz/Qux cells (e.g, http://jsfiddle.net/be5re2oj/), the div and its inner table expands to fill the space.

Currently I'm achieving this effect using jQuery to calculate and set the height, but it seems sloppy and hackish to me. Maybe that's what I have to do considering this ugly table layout, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of going about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is basically to exclude the inner table from the document flow, that can be achieved using absolute positioning:

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#test
{
    overflow-y: scroll;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0; 
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">This is my Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>   
        <th class="nop-border" style="width:10%">Foo</th>
        <td style="width:40%">Lorem ipsum...</td>
        <th style="width:5%">Nop</th>
        <td  style="position:relative;width:45%" rowspan="4">
           &nbsp;
            <div id="test" >
            <table style="width:100%">
                <tr>
                    <th>A</th>
                    <th>B</th>
                    <th>C</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="nop-border" >Bar</th>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="nop-border" >Baz</th>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="nop-border" >Qux</th>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">Call this a footer...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Notice that the table cell which contains the inner table needs to be positioned relatively so that the div will be aligned inside it. Then you set left, right, top and bottom to zero, so the div fits exactly to the cell which was rendered as if it was empty.

Comment: Glad to help! Forgotten to tell that if you need to support browsers which don't understand `top:0;bottom:0` (like ie9, where you original solution doesn't work either)  you may add `overflow-y: scroll` to the cell as well, and remove scrolling from the div if necessary (`if(  $('#test').height()<5) {$('#test').css('overflow-y','visible');}`). Alternatively just set min-height to the div and encourage people to update browsers...

Answer (score 0):

Move one table from another and add big table container to divide view on half.

```
<table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4">This is my Header</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="55%" valign="top">
          first table
        </td>
        <td width="45%" valign="top">
         second table
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g0h5bu75/1/

Comment: This breaks the "footer" row (which in my actual use, is more of the main table), and still uses the same jQuery kludge I'm already using, so I don't think it's the answer I'm looking for.